# `solaris + xargs command for solaris

Tags: linux, find, solaris, xargs, exec

the command

```
find /tmp -name 'core*' -type f -print0 | xargs -0
```

works fine on Linux,
but `xargs -0` option is not legal on Solaris

what is the equivalent option ( `xargs`? ) for Solaris 10

second question:
is it possible to change the syntax:

```
find /tmp -name 'core*' -type f -print0 | xargs -0
```

So it will fit for both OS - Linux and Solaris

I try on my solaris 10 machine:

```
find /tmp -name 'core*' -type f -print0 | xargs -0
xargs: illegal option -- 0
xargs: Usage: xargs: [-t] [-p] [-e[eofstr]] [-E eofstr] [-I replstr] [-i[replstr]] [-L #] [-l[#]] [-n # [-x]] [-s size] [cmd [args ...]]
```

Comment: see if your system has gxargs, possibly in /usr/sfw/bin, or /opt/sfw/bin.  Then you can use the GNU specific options.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both the `-print0` to find and the `-0` to xargs are not POSIX, and may not be available everywhere. The `+` command terminator to `-exec` is part of POSIX, and will accomplish the same task. Here is an example.

```
find /tmp -type f -name 'core*' -exec rm {} +
```

Comment: ok but I cant think right solution and regarding my question , find /tmp -name 'core*' -type f -exec < which other syntax I can put here > in order to print the argument one after one ,

Comment: @yael that's what the `+` terminator does.

Answer (score 1):

The `--print0` and `-0` are GNU extensions. I believe the (almost) full suite of GNU tools is available for Solaris (perhaps under names like `gfind`, probably not installed by default).

[Here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/66415/solaris-default-install-user-tools) is a list of suggested tools to install to make your Solaris experience more pleasant.

Answer (score 0):

Use GNU Parallel in place of xargs:

```
find /tmp -name 'core*' -type f -print | parallel echo
```

It takes literally 10 seconds to install GNU Parallel:

```
wget pi.dk/3 -qO - | sh -x
```

Watch the intro videos to learn more: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1