# Sparc Solaris - install optimised GCC 4.9, 32/64 bit?

Tags: solaris, gcc

We have a new (to us) solaris 10 box running on T4 cpus. Our software stack is Perl/Oracle based. We now have to install GCC 4.9. I wish to optimise this for the T4 CPU. I think the following configure will work:

```
configure --prefix=/app/org/sfw --enable-languages=c,c++ --with-cpu=niagara4
```

Is there anything else I need to do to get an optimised build for gcc 4.9? Any pitfalls I need to be made aware of?

Answer (score 3):

If you really need to "optimize for T4 CPU" then I would guess that Solaris Studio compiler can create code more accurately optimized for T4 than can GCC. Just a guess. Sun/Oracle repeatedly claim that Solaris Studio creates faster code than does GCC. One can imagine this to be true given that T4 is their own CPU. Dunno.

There will not be a license cost to use Solaris Studio.

Have a look at this: [Solaris development host](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/72882/solaris-development-host) on how to set up a Solaris Development Host with either GCC or Solaris Studio.

Also: Solaris 10 is rather old now. You'll have an easier life (because of the software package repos) if you use Solaris 11. Just my two cents on that one.

Comment: Thanks. The client insist on Solaris 10 I'm afraid. I'll look at the Sun resources you provided.

Answer (score 0):

I'd agree at considering using Solaris Studio.

However, Solaris 10 did include a gcc distro (3.x?).  I'd hope that Sun/Oracle compiled it with some smarts for SPARC.  If not installed already, you could try to install the SUNWgcc package from media, or a later Sol10 update.