# Which package do I need for libtool on Solaris?

Tags: solaris, administration

We are a free and open source project, and we are part of Oracle's developer program. We have access to the online developer packages. Solaris 11/64-bit Intel does not include `libtool` in its GNU gear:

```
$ find /usr/gnu -name libtool
$
```

I'm trying to install `libtool`. A simple `pkgadd` is failing:

```
$ sudo pkgadd libtool
pkgadd: ERROR: no packages were found in </var/spool/pkg>
```

When I search for the tool it looks like there are about 23 choices (full result are shown below):

```
$ pkg search libtool | wc -l
    25
```

Thinking the ***`PACKAGE`*** field from `search` might be helpful, I tried:

```
$ sudo pkgadd libtool
pkgadd: ERROR: no packages were found in </var/spool/pkg>
$ sudo pkgadd libtool@2.4.2-0.175.3.0.0.30.0
pkgadd: ERROR: no packages were found in </var/spool/pkg>
$ sudo pkgadd /developer/build/libtool@2.4.2-0.175.3.0.0.30.0
pkgadd: ERROR: no packages were found in </var/spool/pkg>
$ sudo pkgadd pkg:/developer/build/libtool@2.4.2-0.175.3.0.0.30.0
pkgadd: ERROR: no packages were found in </var/spool/pkg>
```

The gap I am experiencing is [How to Add Software Packages (pkgadd)](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19683-01/817-3814/6mjcp0qnh/index.html). The doc does not really explain what we should be doing, or I'm not quite getting it. For example, the Oracle docs don't tell me what `pkgadd`'s `device-name` and `pkgid` are, and I don't know how to dial-in the results from `pkg search`.

I think the general problem is, how do I translate a ***`PACKAGE`*** returned from `pkg search` into a ***`pkg-id`*** used by `pkgadd`?

For this particular problem, which `libtool` is the one customarily found on GNU-based system and how do I install it?

---

```
$ pkg search libtool
INDEX                       ACTION VALUE                             PACKAGE
basename                    file   usr/apr/1.5/build/amd64/libtool   pkg:/library/apr-15@1.5.1-0.175.3.0.0.30.0
basename                    file   usr/apr/1.5/build/libtool         pkg:/library/apr-15@1.5.1-0.175.3.0.0.30.0
basename                    file   usr/apr/1.5/build/sparcv9/libtool pkg:/library/apr-15@1.5.1-0.175.3.0.0.30.0
basename                    file   usr/apr/1.5/build/libtool         pkg:/library/apr-15@1.5.1-0.175.3.0.0.30.0
basename                    file   usr/bin/amd64/libtool             pkg:/developer/build/libtool@2.4.2-0.175.3.0.0.30.0
basename                    file   usr/bin/libtool                   pkg:/developer/build/libtool@2.4.2-0.175.3.0.0.30.0
basename                    file   usr/bin/sparcv9/libtool           pkg:/developer/build/libtool@2.4.2-0.175.3.0.0.30.0
basename                    file   usr/bin/libtool                   pkg:/developer/build/libtool@2.4.2-0.175.3.0.0.30.0
basename                    file   usr/apr/1.3/build/amd64/libtool   pkg:/library/apr-13@1.3.9-0.175.3.0.0.30.0
basename                    file   usr/apr/1.3/build/libtool         pkg:/library/apr-13@1.3.9-0.175.3.0.0.30.0
basename                    file   usr/apr/1.3/build/sparcv9/libtool pkg:/library/apr-13@1.3.9-0.175.3.0.0.30.0
basename                    file   usr/apr/1.3/build/libtool         pkg:/library/apr-13@1.3.9-0.175.3.0.0.30.0
basename                    file   usr/lib/amd64/R/bin/libtool       pkg:/runtime/r@3.2.0-5.12.0.0.0.90.0
basename                    file   usr/lib/sparcv9/R/bin/libtool     pkg:/runtime/r@3.2.0-5.12.0.0.0.90.0
basename                    file   usr/lib/amd64/R/bin/libtool       pkg:/runtime/r@3.2.3-5.12.0.0.0.95.0
basename                    file   usr/lib/sparcv9/R/bin/libtool     pkg:/runtime/r@3.2.3-5.12.0.0.0.95.0
pkg.fmri                    set    solaris/developer/build/libtool   pkg:/developer/build/libtool@2.4.2-0.175.3.0.0.30.0
pkg.summary                 set    GNU libtool                       pkg:/developer/build/libtool@2.4.2-0.175.3.0.0.30.0
pkg.summary                 set    GNU libtool dlopen wrapper        pkg:/library/libtool/libltdl@2.4.2-0.175.3.0.0.30.0
com.oracle.info.description set    GNU libtool                       pkg:/developer/build/libtool@2.4.2-0.175.3.0.0.30.0
com.oracle.info.description set    the GNU libtool dlopen wrapper    pkg:/library/libtool/libltdl@2.4.2-0.175.3.0.0.30.0
com.oracle.info.name        set    libtool                           pkg:/developer/build/libtool@2.4.2-0.175.3.0.0.30.0
com.oracle.info.name        set    libtool                           pkg:/library/libtool/libltdl@2.4.2-0.175.3.0.0.30.0
basename                    dir    usr/share/libtool                 pkg:/developer/build/libtool@2.4.2-0.175.3.0.0.30.0
```

Comment: That "How to Add Software Packages" link is from the Solaris 9 documentation set.   For Solaris 11, you want to use the documentation found under http://www.oracle.com/pls/topic/lookup?ctx=solaris11 instead.

Comment: Thanks @alanc - Please forgive my ignorance... How can you tell? Here's what the page looks like to me, and tere's no versioning information: https://postimg.org/image/80whfg7q5/. (I'd like to avoid the problems in the future).

Comment: The docs for newer releases have a banner across the top showing the version, as you can see on http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E53394_01/html/E54739/pkginstall.html - but for the older releases like that, the only way I know to tell the version is to remove URL components to get to the top level of the library - for your example of https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19683-01/817-3814/6mjcp0qnh/index.html I found the Solaris library version at https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19683-01/ .

Answer (score 2):

Solaris 11 does not use `pkgadd`.

Try:

`pkg install libtool`

For reference `man pkg` on your system or Oracle docs for [pkg](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/E21802/gihhp.html).

Comment: `pkgadd` is for the old SVR4 package system, and only used when installing a package built using it for Solaris 10 or older.  `pkg` is used with the IPS package system that's the primary one in Solaris 11 and later.

Comment: For a general instruction on how to setup a Solaris 11 host with appropriate tools (e.g. libtool, GNU make, etc) for building C/C++ software, have a look at [this SO post](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/72882/solaris-development-host/).