# Top 15 Users in mount level

Tags: solaris

I need to get a list of the Top 15 users (storage) in every mount. I am able to get the mount level information but I am not able to get  the top users in every mount. I can see the nested folders in every mount.

For example;
If I look to mount A, in this I could see folder A folder B folder C and again in each folder i,e Folder A i could more folders A1 A2. This is where my data sets/files are available.

Totally i have around 20 mount point (approx).

OS: Solaris

Comment: Welcome to the U&L SE. What is the criteria for selecting the 'top' users? Storage occupied? Number of files? Something else? Please add one or more examples.

Comment: Storage occupied by top users

Comment: Have you set up [quotas](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/817-0403/sysresquotas-97946/index.html) ?

Comment: No we don't we are trying to make the report who are the top users in every mount and submit to IT team

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
for U in $(cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd) ; do
    C=$(find / -type f -user $U -print0 | du -c --files0-from=- | tail -n 1 | cut -f1 )
    echo $C $U
done | sort -nr
```

This assumes local users and shows the size grouped by file owner which is as close to what you want as possible givin the ambiguity of the question.

https://serverfault.com/questions/632017/solaris-how-to-see-if-bash-is-installed

[Solaris default install (user tools)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/66415/solaris-default-install-user-tools)

https://www.opencsw.org/packages/findutils/

Comment: No its not working.

Comment: @SAM edit your question to show that you can get the list of users and a count for a sample user. Or error output.

Comment: 1st error is illegal operation C and it's coming out.

Comment: Both `find ... -print0` and `du ... --files0-from=-` are non-portable, GNU-specific extensions to the POSIX standard [`find`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html) and [`du`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/du.html) utilities and not likely to work on a non-GNU OS such as Solaris.

Comment: oh! huge stuff ... smoke is out of my ears

Comment: @AndrewHenle thanks I added a link to https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/66415/solaris-default-install-user-tools to make Solaris more compatible.

Comment: @SAM check the links for how to get gfind, gdu, etc.